# sending raw eth packets. when should i close sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, raw-sockets

I implement bridge by taking packets from nfqeueue , open socket to the eth card and send the packets (i have some logic in the middle).

i am new to cpp and low level , so i might ask stupid questions.

if i understand correct i shouldn't open-close the socket for every packet.
i write my code based on this example - http://austinmarton.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/sending-raw-ethernet-packets-from-a-specific-interface-in-c-on-linux/

i open socket like this:

```
sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW))
```

my question are:
1. **for how long the socket alive?**
2. how can i check if the socket i still open?
3. how do i close it? i saw the shutdown , but i didnt know if this is the API?
4. can someone direct me to an example in production level. means handling socket exception ...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep that socket open as long as you have frames to send or receive. Close the socket with normal [`close(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/close.2.html). Here's another raw sockets tutorial for you - http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html

[`shutdown(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) only makes sense with TCP, not at all relevant here.

#### Edit 0:

There's no connection, you are talking ethernet here.

Do yourself a favor and read this book - [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1: The Protocols.](http://www.kohala.com/start/tcpipiv1.html) by W. Richard Stevens - will save you ton of confusion.

Comment: the kernel doesn't close the socket after some time? shouldnt i need to be afraid that the kernel in the other side will close the connection ? is there any specific exception for close connection that i should catch and retry (i need to support 1Gbps)

Comment: The kernel will not close the socket as long as your program is alive. Also since you're sending raw ethernet packets, there's no "connection" anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the book. I will.i look on your example i didnt see (or miss) the setting of the interface index like in my example.